# xpath selector working firefox not in ruby script

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am trying to test a simple scenario, but the xpath doesn't seem to be available, for once I was successful but again kept failing after that for the same xpath.

Please lemme know what is wrong here. Both the xpaths work in firepath, and the first one even works in the script always.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

Given(/^I am on the TRU home page$/) do

browser.get("https://www.toysrus.com")

end

When(/^I search for a product$/) do

browser.find_element(:name,"keyword").send_key("toys")

browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/nav/div/div[2]/div[6]/div").click

end

And(/^Click on first product$/) do

browser.find_element(:xpath,"//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]").click

end

Then(/^Take me to PDP$/) do

pending

end
```

Comment: Two observations: 1. Absolute xpaths are prone to errors, so even if it did work now it would likely fail later. 2. You could be running into an issue where it's trying to click the second **XPath** before that element actually exists on the page since it's waiting for something triggered by the previous click.

Some more detail on exactly what you're seeing, **html** of the element you're trying to click, and the error you're getting would be needed to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Please don't use browser-generated XPath. It is brittle because it checks for things you don't care about, and it probably doesn't check for meaningful things (IDs and relevant classes).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Instead of absolute `xpath` you can consider constructing logical `xpath`. Here are the `xpath` which you can use:

1. Passing the text `toys` within Search:

   ```
   browser.find_element(:xpath,"//input[@name='keyword']").send_key("toys")
   ```
2. Clicking on `Search` button:

   ```
   browser.find_element(:xpath,"//div[@class='search-icon-tru']").click
   ```
3. Click on first product:

   ```
   browser.find_element(:xpath,"//div[@class='product-item__product-title'] [contains(.,'The Peanut Shell Bella Elephant Plush')]").click
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.